# Form cannot be submitted via jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have simple form

```
<form id="formToSubmit1" action="?action=send&to=med" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="data" value="data" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hiddenData" value="hiddenData" /> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit" /> 
</form>
```

And I woud like to submit it from multiple places so I made own link

```
<span class="likeLink" id="submitLinkToForm1">Submit</span>
```

and here is my code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery( "#submitLinkToForm1" ).click(function() {
           jQuery("#formToSubmit1").submit();
     });
});
```

and it does not work.. or show any error. Any ideas?

Comment: yes this is not the only script i have the other ones works fine

Comment: did you add the script in a dom ready handler

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/WWnHP/1/

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/RN6Bf/

Comment: I think i will look somewhere else, there no multiple id´s or multiple class or any different basic mistakes anyway thx for fiddles

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
                  {
                      $('#submitLinkToForm1').click(function()
                        {
                            $('#formToSubmit1').submit();
                        });
                  });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wM7L7/)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of jQuery needs to be run onDocuemntReady. This is because your html havn't been renderd in the browser if you try to attach the submit eventlistner before this.

You can achieve this by placing your code inside a documentReady eventlistner like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
     jQuery( "#submitLinkToForm1" ).click(function() {
             jQuery("#formToSubmit1").submit();
     });
});
```

Comment: i have wrapped it into dom rady my mistake i should write it above

Comment: try changing jQuery => $ Your code is intact from what i can see other wise

Comment: when i changed jquery to $ it gives me error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'submit' of null

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you have multiple `id` with the same name, try to use `class` instead.

```
<span class="likeLink submitLinkToForm1">Submit</span>
```

then you can do:

```
jQuery("body").on('click', '.submitLinkToForm1' , function() {
    jQuery("#formToSubmit1").submit();
});
```

Comment: Where does he use same id?

Comment: nice idea i checked it but there is no multiple id in my script

Comment: @user2826311 Did you include jQuery properly or receive any error in the console?